# A couple of requests with user@ in URL lead to "Policy breach notice" from Google AdSense

Tags: javascript, web, nginx, basic-authentication

I've recently got an email from Google, saying that they are going to ban my AdSense account because I'm sending Personally Identifiable Information to them with my Google AdSense tag requests. It says that around 1% of requests from my website have a referrer of:

```
some_user@my_website.com/some/subpage
```

and they consider some_user@my_website.com to be PII (even though it can be completely made up abcd1234@my_website.com). More on this here: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6163366?hl=en .

I never link to this kind of URLs (the only form I use is my_website.com/some/subpage), but I guess my users sometimes enter it manually (since product-wise my website is providing an email service, it may seem reasonable by some logic).

I figured URI of some_user@my_website.com/some/subpage is legal since http basic auth allows for specifying user like this. When I entered it manually to Firefox, some_user@ disappears from the location bar but in the Net panel of Firebug I can see all files are indeed requested from some_user@my_website.com/some/subpage and that's how Google sees it too.

I though that as a brute-force solution even something like:

```
if uri contains '@':
  redirect to my_website.com
```

would do.

I'm using NGINX/UWSGI/Python Paste + JS. I've tried to implement the above condition both on server side and in JS, but my URI always says my_website.com/some/subpage even if I manually put some_user@my_website.com/some/subpage in the browser address bar.

I've also tried configuring basic_auth in NGINX to disallow providing any user but with no effect.

How do I get rid of these requests?
How do I get the FULL URI (with some_user@) in JS? I tried document.URI and window.location.href but they didn't contain the user part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently presence of user@ part in the URI can be detected by examining `window.location.href`. I haven't noticed it before since **`window.location.href` only contains user@ in Webkit-based browsers (e.g. Chrome, Opera, Safari) but not in Firefox**!

To resolve the problem I've added a check on that in JS + a JS redirect to an URL without user[:password]@.

Hopefully Google uses the same variable to figure out referrer for the ad requests, so it get PII only from Webkit browsers & fixing it for Webkit suffices. Will keep you posted.